# How to return value from asp.net page called by jQuery Get() Method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

How to return some value from asp.net page that is called using jQuery Get() method ? The get method is given below and i want the alert() should display the returned value.

The get() calls "result.aspx" page that return a string and that string i want to show in alert().

```
$.get("result.aspx",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "India"
    },
    function (result, status, xhr) {
        alert(result);
    }
);
```

The result.aspx code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadReturn();
    }
}
void LoadReturn()
{
    string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
    string city = Request.QueryString["city"];
    string returnValue="Hello Mr."+ name + " who lives in " + city;

    //How to return value of returnValue to the jquery get() function. 

}
```

How to return value of returnValue to the jquery get() function ??

**Update**
I tried the response.write(). It is able to return the data to jquery get() method.

```
Response.Write(returnValue);
```

Only problem is that it is also sending me the full HTML of the result.aspx page. Which i don't want. 
[image]
How can i prevent the unnecessary HTML from reaching the jquery get() method?

Comment: use a `WebMethod` or a separate .svc webservice file. aspx pages are designed to serve a whole HTML page from a full page load, not fragments of HTML or JSON to an ajax call. This tutorial gives a nice simple example using a `WebMethod`. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: i know about the .ajax() method but how to return with .get() in asp.net?

Comment: Have you tried Response.End() following Response.Write() ? ADysons answer is probably the correct way forward if you're not just looking for a quick fix though.

Comment: @gb2d i haven't tried the Response.End();. I did it now the extra unnecessary page HTML is gone. Problem resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting Response.End() in the end. Hope it helps others too.

```
void LoadReturn()
{
    string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
    string city = Request.QueryString["city"];
    string returnValue="Hello Mr."+ name + " who lives in " + city;

    Response.Write(returnValue);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: this definitely helped me as well!